# How to pass a variable reference to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Suppose I have the following react-native code, in which I want the "press" function to be different based on the value of `bProps.type`:

```
const press = bProps.type > 0 
    ? props.function1(arg1, arg2) 
    : props.function2(arg1, arg2);
return <Button onPress={press}></Button>;
```

But the problem is that both `function1` and `function2` seem to be called before pressing the buttons, and pressing the buttons doesn't seem to call these functions. Is there a way I can set the value of "press" so that pressing the buttons calls the right functions?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are **calling** the function and assigning its return value to `press`.

You need to create a *new* function (which will call the function you want to call with arguments when it itself is called by the event being triggered).

```
const press = bProps.type > 0 
    ? function() { props.function1(arg1, arg2) }
    : function() { props.function2(arg1, arg2) };
return <Button onPress={press}></Button>;
```

or

```
const press = bProps.type > 0 
    ? props.function1.bind(null, arg1, arg2) }
    : props.function2.bind(null, arg1, arg2) };
return <Button onPress={press}></Button>;
```

or

```
const press = bProps.type > 0 
    ? () => props.function1(arg1, arg2)
    : () => props.function2(arg1, arg2);
return <Button onPress={press}></Button>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const press = bProps.type > 0 
    ? () => props.function1(arg1, arg2) 
    : () => props.function2(arg1, arg2);
return <Button onPress={press}></Button>;
```

The original code had to evaluate function1 and function2 before it could evaluate the ternary operator.  Wrapping them in lambdas means the lambdas need to be evaluated, but that doesn't mean they are immediately called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const press = bProps.type > 0 ? props.function1 : props.function2;
return <Button onPress={() => press(arg1,arg2)}></Button>;
```